# jQuery and object-oriented JavaScript - howto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I've read [this](http://www.sweetvision.com/2009/07/07/how-to-use-object-oriented-programming-with-jquery/) and [this](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/HJS) (thanks google)
But it doesn't help enough. I'd like to know, if, straight out of the box, without any plugin addons, it's possible to do something like it's possible with prototype, for example:

```
MyClass = Class.create(Table,
{
  cookieName: 'w_myclass',
  prefix: 'myclass',
    ...blabla...

  // function
  initStr: function()
  {
    ...blabla...
  },

  // another function
  getIndice: function(param)
  {
    ...blabla...
    return 0;
  }

});
```

Any idea/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why not use javascript's native object-orientation features?

Comment: JavaScript is about as "object-oriented" as it gets. You're asking about class-based inheritance, not OO-ness.

Comment: there is no out-of-box solution. But there is another language http://coffeescript.org/ which compiles one-to-one into the equivalent JS, so you can use features of coffescript with every js framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a near object oriented solution using javascript with jquery you can define an object in javascript that will set up your event controllers.

The second half of this post http://www.codescream.com/?p=18 covers that. but i'll write here a resume on how to make an object in javascript that you can use in a near object oriented structure.

It would look something like this:

```
function myObject(constructorParam1, constructorParam2, anotherOne, blabla){

  var text = "";
  // this event will be set everyTime you run myObject
  $(".foo").click(function(){
    text = $(this).text(); // copies the text inside the elements ".foo" to a local variable
    doSomething();
  });

  function aPrivateFunction1(){


  }

  function aPrivateFunction2(){

  }

  function internalAdd(a,b){
    return a+b;
  }

  var size = 1; // privateVaribale
  var name = blabla;


  if(name===undefined){
     name="No name";
  }

  aPrivateFunction1(); // run "aPrivateFunction1()

  // you can consider all code above as being part of the constructor.
  // The variables declared above are private, and the functions are private as well

  // bellow are public functions  that you can access in an OOP manner
  return {
    getSize: function(){
        return size;
    },

    setSize: function(newSize){
        size = newSize;
    },

    getName: function(){
        return name;
    },

    setName: function(newName){ 
        name = newname;
    },

    addAndTurnPositive: function(n1,n2){
        var val = internalAdd(n1,n2);
        if(val<0){
            return val*-1;
        }
        return val;
    }
  }
}

// then you can run it like
var anInstance = myObject("aaa",1234,"asdak",123);
anInstance.setSize(1234);
var t = anInstance.addAndTurnPositive(-5,2);
```

Comment: I feel that this kind of thing can be very off-putting to a novice JS programmer who isn't used to dealing with closure. A wise colleague once told me that your goal should be to never write anything on top of native JavaScript; find a framework.

Comment: He asked how to use javacript in a more object oriented manner. This is it :p and I disagree with what you just said.

Comment: That's okay. It's my opinion but I think it's one that many people share.

Comment: It's not because you're part of the "many people" that it inevitably proves you're right. The chances are higher, but it's not a de-facto conclusion. And fmsf is right: I was looking for a way to write kind of "oriented javascript" with jQuery, and if nothing exists (as it seems to be), his example is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your suggestion Tony, and thanks for your answer, fmsf. I like K.I.S.S. and I'm a JavaScript newbie, so I'll begin to code my object-oriented stuff this way, even though it might not be the best option .

Comment: @OlivierDofus thanks :) but if this your "correct answer" please mark it as such

Comment: I should note that the link in my answer to Doug Crockford is a great place to start if you're interested in programming JS this way. Just don't give me dirty looks if your codebase grows large and you don't know what to do =)

Answer (score 6):

JQuery never had the purpose of being a class framework. It's about page manipulation and tools (like AJAX). You can pound a nail with a fork, but why not use a hammer?

Using native JavaScript to create a class-based inheritance system is asking for trouble unless you're a highly skilled JavaScript programmer. [Douglas Crockford will tell you it's possible](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html), but he has a deep understanding if the intricacies of closure etc etc. Also, using native inheritance features becomes unsustainable very quickly if your system grows large.

I highly recommend James Coglan's [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/) framework. The class definitions will look almost identical to your example. It's not native JS but it works fine with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. jQuery doesn't offer any class and inheritance functionality. You'd need to include another library, such as [klass](http://dustindiaz.com/klass) (although there is a [jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-klass/) which ties it in more closely with jQuery)

Comment: There is no code for the jQuery-klass plugin. The project seems dead since 2008. Someone decided to create a new project and to recreate the code. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-klass-plugin/