# Proper class construction in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, class

I am learning OO programming in Javascript and there seems to be many ways to create a class. I've managed to distill much of what I read into a generic structure, but I feel like I might be missing the purpose of prototyping to save on bloat. Does including the prototype definition in this "class" make them pointless (ie not reducing object size)? Are there any flaws in this overall structure?

Thanks,

```
var Car = (function () {

    //Private fields
    var _make;
    var _model;

    //Constants (protected by encapsulation)    
    var NUM_OF_WHEELS = 4;

    //Private methods
    function getDesc() {
        return _make + " " + _model;
    }

    //Public constructor
    function thisCar(make, model, color) {
        _make = make;
        _model = model;

        //public properties
        thisCar.prototype.color = color;
    }

    //static properties
    thisCar.carsInTheWorld = 50;

    //static methods
    thisCar.getNumberOfWheels = function () {
        return NUM_OF_WHEELS * thisCar.carsInTheWorld;
    };

    //public properties
    thisCar.prototype.color = "";

    //public method
    thisCar.prototype.startEngine = function () {
        console.log(getDesc() + " engine started");
    };

    return thisCar;
})();
```

**EDIT**
After reading the comments and the links provided here is what I understand.

Members of the class that require access to private members cannot be added to the prototype and have to be privileged. As well, it is common practice to not include the prototype in the constructor function.

```
var Car = function (make, model, color) {//Public constructor
    //Private fields
    var _make = make;
    var _model = model;

    //Public fields 
    this.color = color; 

    //Private methods
    function getDesc() {
        return _make + " " + _model;
    }

    //Privileged functions (requiring private members) 
    this.startEngine = function () {
        console.log(getDesc() + " engine started");
    };
};

//public method
Car.prototype.sprayPaint = function (newColor) {
    var oldColor = this.color;
    this.color = newColor;
    console.log("Your car has changed from " + oldColor + " to " + newColor);
};

//Public fields  (if not declared in constuctor)
Car.prototype.fuel = 0; 

//static properties
Car.carsInTheWorld = 0;

//static methods
Car.getNumberOfWheels = function () {               
    var NUM_OF_WHEELS = 4;
    return NUM_OF_WHEELS * Car.carsInTheWorld;
};
```

Thanks for all your responses, they really helped.

Comment: Personally this kind of coding in JS makes me cringe. It's an incredibly dynamic language and you're right - there are lots of ways to do everything. I would desperately plead to you that you eventually use a class framework (such as JS.Class).

Comment: There are lots of problems with your code, too many to go into details here. You can look at my post for types on *correct* inheritance in JS http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: Frankly upon seeing your code, You should read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) guide to get started with Object Oriented Javascript

Comment: Juan and Starx. Neither of those guides/articles deal with private variables or methods. As well, I have not even though about touching inheritance yet :) I have to agree though, that without private variables this could be written much better.

Comment: Tony R: I will look into that framework. It might be better then reinventing the wheel. But I like this problem because it is forcing me to really understand the language.

Comment: Go for it bro. I had to learn this crap too. But the day I started using JS.Class was the last day I *ever* typed `prototype` again. You simply don't have to worry about these details of the language anymore. It becomes about writing your domain logic and not about how to implement inheritance in JavaScript. Don't get me wrong, though - JS.Class has its own learning curve. It's easier if you come from Ruby.

Comment: My advice is to learn stuff as you need it. For a basic object with public-only properties and no intialization step, we have object literals "{}". For public vs private methods/props with private instance vars, an initialization step, or passing arguments the object can reference, you want a constructor. When things get more complicated, and the limitations of prototype start to rear their head, I recommend moving towards a composite object strategy and discovering limitations in that before seeking inheritance. Also, JS is excellent for event-driven systems.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using prototype, a common pattern is to return an object from the constructor that contains your public accessors/mutators:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwCSd/2/)

```
function Car() {
  var myPrivateVar = "foo";
  var myPublicVar = "bar";

  function myPrivateFunc() {console.log(myPrivateVar);};
  myPrivateFunc();      

  return {
    getMyPublicVar: function() {
      return myPublicVar;
    }
  }
}
var honda = Car();
console.log(honda.getMyPublicVar());
honda.myPrivateFunc();    // fail
```

Use prototype outside of the class definition to add properties to it. You would use `Car.prototype.myFunc = function() {};` *after* `Car` is already defined to add `myFunc` to `Car` objects instantiated in the future. These added members are public.

[Here's a question that should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861151/jquery-and-object-oriented-javascript-howto#comment11071509_8861151)

[Here's the standard article from Crockford on doing inheritance this way.](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)

I should reiterate that using a class framework such as [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/) will save you countless headaches when your code grows large.

Comment: No. Constructors do not (must not) return objects.

Comment: Yea sorry, my stucture was a bit wrong. It's not a constructor, it's a "constructor." In the OO sense, not in the technical JavaScript sense in that you do not call `new Car()`. But it still creates a closure in which you can have privacy and and interface that is returned from Car().

Comment: There are plenty of native JS constructors that can be invoked as a constructor or a function. String for instance. It strikes me as a good idea to branch your return statements but I don't think they have any effect on the object instantiation other than halting the process at the point of the return.

Comment: Yea I was just testing it; you can indeed use `new Car()` with this pattern.

Comment: Yes, you can use `new Car`. Though, it does not act as a constructor and the object returned is not a `instanceof Car`.

Comment: +1 actually, Doug Crockford does like this type [(Power Constructor + Parasitic inheritance)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=DwYPG6vreJg#t=1511s) of building objects, especially without the `new`

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed up a closure and the objectorientated constructor things. Usually, you start without a closure. In JS, you define your "class" by a constructor function:

```
var Car = function Car(model) { //Public constructor

    // Private fields of one instance
    // model is an argument
    var make;

    // Private methods of one instance
    function getDesc() {
        return make + " " + model;
    }

    // Public fields of one instance
    this.color = "#555";

    // Public methods of one instance, privileged the access private fields and functions
    this.setMake = function(m) {
        make = m;
    };
    this.desc = function() {
        return getDesc();
    };
} // end of constructor

/* now the prototype things: */   

// public "default" fields, may get overwritten per instance
Car.prototype.color = "";

// public methods, can only access other public things (not "privileged")
thisCar.prototype.startEngine = function () {
    console.log(this.desc() + " engine started");
};
```

That's it. Now, you may add static things. They have nothing to do with the `Car` function, but often they get namespaced by beeing properties of the constructor. But they could also be free variables.

```
var carsInTheWorld = 50;
// or
Car.livingInstances = 50;
// or something

Car.NUM_OF_WHEELS = 4; // constants are uppercase
```

Only if you need to have static, private variables - e.g. the instances-counter - you may build a closure around everything. Then the unnamespaced variables are only accessible from inside that closure function.

Comment: Doesn't this.desc essentially expose getDesc() making it no longer private? I think my issue here is that I don't think you can really mix adding methods to the prototype and private methods/variables.

Comment: Yes, in this example it does and is nearly equal to `this.desc = getDesc;`. But I only wanted to show the usage of a private function in a privileged one. Adding another example.

Answer (score 2):

Think of prototype as a backup repository of methods attached directly to the instance constructor function. If you try to call a property/method on an instance that doesn't have it, the instance's constructor's prototype is then checked for the method. The bummer is that the prototype property can't see inside the instance (to access instance vars).

I encourage you to avoid immediately pouncing on libraries that chain prototypes in order to allow for complex class-like inheritance schemes.

Mostly because this approach tends to stink. It's inflexible, difficult to read and not really a good fit for the sorts of problems JS is good at handling in the first place. (actually such schemes overdone are lousy and recommended against in any language). I'm not saying inheritance is bad, just that the holy grail of JavaScript is not to write bad Java and by that I mean 20 layer deep sets of cascading inheritance completely undecipherable and unalterable by anybody who hasn't spent a couple days looking at them recently.

Don't worry about encapsulation. No really. When is the last time you heard of a front end or UI dev rewriting key innards of jQuery on a complex eCommerce site  or changing JQ object methods and other properties directly so it would be useful for something they were working on without a care for all the other stuff that might break? "Trust the user" as the Python kids say. Private instance vars can help clarify what's interface and what's not. Beyond that utility, put it out of your mind and on the internet where everybody can always see our code anyway.

And learn everything you can about functions in JS. There's a lot of stuff going on there that can be useful in JS OOP, where the focus tends to be more on the instances than the constructors. Functions, context and the call/apply methods are keys to coming up with structures that work for you.

Comment: To be honest, so far object literals have more then been enough so far. I like to keep my OO on the server. But I really wanted to understand the language and 'best' practices. The class seems to be a good learning tool.

Comment: FYI I liked your response, and I will likely avoid too much encapsulation and inheritance, but the other response was closer to the  question.

Comment: I'm not offended. I just like to help out with the often-poorly-explained prototype property. Take the rest as me jumping on any excuse to rant about things. I also recommend understanding jQuery under the hood and reading Design Patterns for language context on a lot of the bigger OOP paradigms (even the patterns that don't serve much of a purpose in JS have given me ideas).

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is fine.  This bit is wrong, though:

```
function thisCar(make, model, color) {
    // [ ... ]
    //public properties
    thisCar.prototype.color = color;
}
```

Inside the constructor, you should not assign anything to the prototype.  That assigns the color property to all Cars created from the constructor.

Instead, do this:

```
    this.color = color;
```

And to answer the general question, it is not pointless to use the prototype this way.  The outer function will only run once, right after the script is parsed.  It will assign the internal thisCar constructor to `Car`.  The prototype properties are properly placed, with the exception noted above.

One other suggestion, though, is that even internally to your IIFE, you should use an uppercase initial letter for the name.  I personally would use `Car` here too, as it seems clearer.

EDIT:

There is more wrong than I saw at first.  This is also wrong

```
var _make;
var _model;

// [ ... ]
function thisCar(make, model, color) {
    _make = make;
    _model = model;
}
```

These are not instance properties.

Moreover, there is no real way that I know of to combine the use of the prototype with closure-based private properties.  So I think you're trying to do too much together.